# Где и если можно, как сделать изменение данных к определенной дате?

Tags: c#, postgresql

Есть таблица в ней имеется статус и дата окончания действия активное статуса, т.е. c true на false в определенную дату. Имеются ли в Postgres средства для реализации этого или делать это в C#?

Comment: СУБД обеспечивает лишь контроль ваших данных, а не выполнение каких либо логических операций. Лучше сделать это C#, проверять при каждом обращении к БД, или сделать фоновый процесс

Comment: проще сделать проверку на C# на дату. А флаг вообще выкинуть и вычислять